# Configuring admin to display thumnails

Tags: python, django

I am trying to config my admin so that it will display thumbnails of the picture. Everything I click on the thumbnail (without the picture) it will link me to my project home page, instead of viewing the image.

URL output after clicking thumbnail:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/portfolio/photo/%7B%20MEDIA_URL%20%7D%s
```

This is what is looks like currently:

[image]

Not sure why the images are being displayed =/

```
Here is my models.py for app:

from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from PIL import Image
from Boothie.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
import os.path
from django.utils.html import format_html



class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # thumbnail = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def images(self):
        lst = [x.photo.title for x in self.photo_set.all()]
        return lst

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Set search_fields to enable a search box on the admin change list page.
    # This should be set to a list of field names that will be searched whenever
    # somebody submits a search query in that text box.
    search_fields = ["title"]
    # Set list_display to control which fields are displayed on the change list page of the admin.
    list_display = ["title"]


class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to="album")
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # thumbnail = models.ImageField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Save image dimensions
        # Save image
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # get image
        pic = Image.open(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.photo))
        # set Photo width and height
        self.width, self.height = pic.size
        # save object
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def albums_(self):
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values-list
        lst = [x[1] for x in self.album.value_list()]
        return ', '.join(lst)

    def size(self):
        # Photo size
        return "%s x %s" % (self.width, self.height)

    def thumbnail(self):
        # return """<a href="/media/%s"><img border="0" alt="" src="/media/%s" height="40" /></a>""" % (self.image.name, self.image.name)
        thumbnail_html = format_html("<a href=\"{{ MEDIA_URL }}%s\"><img border=\"0\" alt=\"\" src=\"{{ MEDIA_URL }}%s\" height=\"40\" /></a>", self.photo.name, self.photo.name)
        return thumbnail_html

    # thumbnail.allow_tags = True

class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title", "photo"]
    list_display = ["photo", "thumbnail", "title", "album", "size"]
    list_filter = ["album"]
```

settings.py media settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../media_root/Boothie/pics")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from portfolio.models import Album, AlbumAdmin, Photo, PhotoAdmin

admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you already defined `MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL` in your settings, then just add the following code in your url.py file and that should do the trick.

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`{{ MEDIA_URL }}` is a template tag use it in templates.

In python code do:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.MEDIA_URL
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to Django so I'm not sure what to do with this information. I put `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` because it is loaded html into my admin page? Also I  have this `from Boothie.settings import MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL`. I tried this little bit http://dpaste.com/3JTTWVW and I am getting the same result =/

Comment: In other words, `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` is only available templates. You are constructing a link in Python code. Not in your template. In your python code add `print '{{ MEDIA_URL  }}'` and on a new line `print settings.MEDIA_URL`. Load the page and look in your console what is printed...